# first instantiated SimplePie object cosumes 5mb?

Tags: php, functions

This following lines causes 5mb memory consumption. It appears large to me.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'SimplePie' ) ) include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-feed.php' );        
new SimplePie();
```

I'm using php 5.2.4, WordPress 3.5.1.

With PHP 5.4.3, the memory usage with the above lines becomes 2.25mb.

I'd like to know a way to reduce it if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. It is caused by a bug in PHP 5.2 and is fixed in PHP 5.3.

You need to manually call the destructor method before unsetting the $feed and $item variables.

[source](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/i_m_getting_memory_leaks)